# Prerequisites for Angular 2

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'd like to write a small homepage. 
Therefore, I already have a jee REST-Server set up and would like to use Angular 2 to display the data.

I bought a package at One.com thinking I would not need any application servers to run Angular 2, as it is executed on the client side.

So, before I start coding: is it possible to build a small app without having too much trouble setting things up?
One.com doesn't seem to be offering any Node.js support but lets me set up a PHP server.

Something to mention: the REST-service is hosted at openshift. However, it is accessible under a subdomain of my one.com domain. I guess, there shouldn't be any SOP violations because of this.

Comment: Yes. You can always create a localhost server and then move it to a domain.

Comment: Are you talking about creating a local e.g. Node.js server and copying that on to the webspace? I am not experienced in the javascript environment but that doesn't sound like it would work

Comment: It works fine, provided the server-sided language you are using on the local and main server are the same. Every single working web developer will (*should*) write code locally through a cloned repository and not move it to the main server until the code was verified and tested to work. It's also common to switch to a local database copy while you develop and test code.

Comment: With One.com, everything is file based. Like you said, no application server (no Nodejs). But there is likely Apache, which allows for hosting PHP files to handle server-side things. CORS would be an issue unless One.com allows you to enable CORS. Short answer, yes you can do it with what you have. So, go for it!

Comment: So, I just managed to append "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" to every request through modifying .htaccess, thus enabling CORS. Therefore, I should be able to query my subdomain. As far as my understanding goes, I should be able to have Angular running without any server and drawbacks, right?